# MySQL_Trigger_Problem_Uknown_Col

Tags: mysql, sql, testing, architecture

I'm quite new to making triggers in MySQL SO AH. Here's my problem line of code:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER trigME BEFORE INSERT ON user_accounts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO user_logs(user_id,date_entry) values (NEW.user_id,now());
END |
```

It returns an error saying :

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) Unknown column 'user_id' in 'NEW'

Been spending around hours in searching solutions to aid these, kindly help me please :))

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE statement for `user_accounts` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your syntax in my own MySQL 5.5.15 database and on versions 5.1.61, 5.5.30 & 5.6.6 at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94f7d5/1) and it worked fine on all of them. Click [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94f7d5/1) to see.

So, first of all, double check you have the correct column name.

If you do, then it could be related to your version of MySQL. In the [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html), there are some examples where they `INSERT` the `NEW` values into another table using an unusual syntax similar to `UPDATE` like this...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigME BEFORE INSERT ON user_accounts
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_logs SET user_id = NEW.user_id, date_entry = NOW();
  END;
```

Or you could also try reading into a variable `new_user_id` and use that in your `INSERT` instead...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigME BEFORE INSERT ON user_accounts
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE new_user_id INT;
    SET new_user_id = NEW.user_id;
    INSERT INTO user_logs(user_id, date_entry) values (new_user_id, NOW());
  END;
```

**Note for future readers:** see comments below about SUPER privileges...

Comment: All of my column names are correct DAV. I've read the MySQL documentation and it says i need SUPER privileges into making triggers. So what i did in the console is Assigned 'Super Privilege into root. Though i think in all aspect root can access and create all functions and necessary procedures in the first place, or i might be wrong? or somethings wrong in my MySQL server. Anyways that resolved my problem.. Thanks for the help DAV :D !

Comment: Cool, no probs. I also had that issue when I tried on another database, but it told me directly that I need 'super' privileges.